# Memory leak in c due to the malloc

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

I am getting the memory leak due to first malloc call. I tried to comment out and free but there is no way that I can fix it.
The code wants to parse the query than put the information inside the map. At the same time it is going to update struct too

```
   
        row_ = atoi(strtok(NULL,",:"));
        col_ = atoi(strtok(NULL,",:"));
       
    }
}
```

Comment: `!strcmp(&query[j], ",")` will only be true when `j` is `strlen(query) - 1` and the final character of `query` is `','`. You likely meant `query[j] == ','` (possibly initialize `count` to `1`).

Comment: _"memory leak due to first malloc call"_ - what `malloc` call? There are no `malloc` calls at all in the code you've shown

Answer (score 0):

For starters this for loop

```
for(int j = 0; j < strlen(query); j++){
    if(!strcmp(&query[j], ",")){
        count++;
    }
}
```

does not make a sense. It seems you mean instead

```
for(int j = 0; j < strlen(query); j++){
    if( query[j] == ',')){
        count++;
    }
}
```

You allocated memory and its address is assigned to the pointer `type`.

```
char* type = malloc(sizeof(char *));
//      char* char_name= (char *)malloc(1);
```

then the pointer was reassigned

```
type = strtok(query, ",:");
```

So the address of the allocated memory is lost and you have a memory leak.

This commented declaration

```
char* char_name= (char *)malloc(1);
```

also invokes a memory leak due to the statement

```
char_name = strtok(NULL,",:");
```

This statement

```
char_name = realloc(char_name, sizeof(char_name)+1);
```

does not make a sense at least because `sizeof( char_name )` is equivalent to `sizeof( char * )`. It seems you mean at least

```
char_name = realloc(char_name, strlen(char_name) + 2 );
```

But in any case you may not reallocate the memory using the pointer because it does not point to a dynamically allocated memory after this statement

```
    char_name = strtok(NULL,",:");
```

Answer (score -1):

examine these 2 lines of code

```
char* type=malloc(sizeof(char *)); <<<<<<=======
//      char* char_name= (char *)malloc(1);
int row_,col_;
int count =0;

for(int j=0;j<strlen(query);j++){
    if(!strcmp(&query[j],",")){
        count++;
    }
}
count=(count+1)/3;

type = strtok(query, ",:");   <<<<<<=======
```

You `malloc` some memory, do nothing with it and then overwrite the pointer. So now there is no way to free it or use it.

As far as I can see you just need

```
 char*type = NULL;
```

and take out the frees of `type` too.

Note - I have not verified the rest of the code. Just answered your leak question. The way you are using strtok is certainly not idiomatic. And I suspect that you think

```
 type = strtok(query, ",:");
```

copies the first token into the buffer pointed at by type. It does not, what you need is this

```
 type = strdup(strtok(query, ",:"));
```

Likewise the assignments in the loop

```
char_name = strtok(NULL,",:");
char_name = realloc(char_name, sizeof(char_name)+1);
```

are very wrong. You cannot realloc the return of strtok. Again you need

```
char_name = strdup(strtok(NULL,",:"));
```

Comment: I have tried to use strdup but it gives error as following:                      
main.c:214:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strdup' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  char* type = strdup(strtok(query, ",:"));
  ^
main.c:214:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  char* type = strdup(strtok(query, ",:"));
               ^
main.c:218:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   char* char_name =strdup(strtok(NULL,",:"));

Comment: @Sude https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html, include <string.h> , if windows its called `_strdup`

Comment: @pm100: on linux, it's the feature test macro which needs added: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before the first `#include`.